# TensorFlow doesn't learn when input=output (or probably I am missing something)

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have used TensorFlow before for training a model to recognize images (something similar to this example: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). I was trying to do something similar with inception-v4 from scratch (using the model from https://github.com/tensorflow/models). But it was not working, it wasn't learning, so I decided to reduce my code and simplify everything. The model is a hidden layer with the same neurons as inputs and what the model has to learn is that input=output. Seems pretty simple and easy, but the results of my code are far from good.

I have tried different things: sigmoid cross entropy instead of softmax cross entropy, other optimizers, different learning rates, models more comples with more neuros and more layers, reduce_sum instead of reduce mean for the loss ... But the only times I got "good results" (>90%) it seems because the model falls into a local minimum and I am not able to replicate them. Usually I see 70% precision with a high loss (>=0.7).

My conclusion is that there is something wrong in my code that I am not able to spot and that is the reason the learning process is slow and get stuck at high losses. Otherwise the code with inception-v4 for images will at least learn something and don't get the loss stuck at the same value all the time.

```
import os
import random
import shutil

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.layers as layers

# parameters
max_steps = 10000
batch_size = 64
output_size = 10
summary_path = './summary'

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    shape = [batch_size, output_size]
    inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape, name='inputs')
    outputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=shape, name='outputs')
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    logits = layers.fully_connected(inputs, output_size)
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.1, global_step, max_steps / 3, 0.1,
                                               name='learning_rate')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, outputs, name='loss'))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    input_label = tf.argmax(inputs, axis=1) # vector with the input labels
    output_label = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1) # vector with the predicted labels
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

# prepare summary
if os.path.exists(summary_path):
    shutil.rmtree(summary_path)
os.makedirs(summary_path)
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(summary_path, graph=graph)

with tf.Session(graph=graph).as_default() as session:
    session.run(init_op)
    to_run = {'step': global_step, 'loss': loss, 'logits': logits, 'train_op': train_op,
              'learning_rate': learning_rate, 'summary': summary_op,
              'in_label': input_label, 'out_label': output_label}
    step = 0
    while step < max_steps:
        # fake input
        data = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            data[i, random.randint(0, output_size - 1)] = 1.0
        # run
        results = session.run(to_run, feed_dict={inputs: data, outputs: data})
        # print data
        step, in_label, out_label = results['step'],  results['in_label'], results['out_label']
        precision = (in_label == out_label).sum() * 100.0 / batch_size
        print('step: {0}/{1}  learning rate: {2:.4f}  loss: {3:.4f}  precision: {4:.1f}%'
              .format(step, max_steps, results['learning_rate'], results['loss'], precision))
        summary_writer.add_summary(results['summary'], step)
    # print last batch
    print(data)
    print(results['logits'])
    print(in_label)
    print(out_label)
    print('precision {}%'.format(precision))

summary_writer.flush()
```

[image: learning rate and loss graphs]